# How to create bump material in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Anyway to create this type of Material. Confuse with 2-3 type of bump seen. And some white parts (Peanut). Can it be achieve by material or sculpting or cycles material

[image]

Tried to create with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38DwOgqOY-c). Did not work. Any suggestion or help now to create the material in Cycles. Thanks

Comment: What *exactly* does not work?

Comment: you could mix procedural material and particles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subdivide a cube, sculpt it a bit:

[image]

Give it some noise and bumps:

[image]

And at last create a particle system for the peanuts:

[image]

Comment: wow its really awesome. Thanks can u plz share the file.

Comment: sure here it is: https://pasteall.org/blend/093afb9e54d347f98eb6a04f5dd02235

Comment: Thanks its really looking awesome